# Postgis - one circles contains another

Tags: postgresql, postgis, coordinate-systems

I'm using postgis with gps data, and trying to figure out if one circle with a GPS coordinate and radius (in meters), contains another.

I'm able to do it if I'm not using GPS coordinates, but just points on a graph, but this doesn't work if I substitute with lat and lon points:

```
-- A circle within a circle
SELECT ST_Contains(bigc,smallc) As bigcontainssmall
FROM (SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(21, 38)::geography, 40) As smallc,
         ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(21, 39)::geography, 400) AS bigc) foo;
```

Thoughts?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get an empty result or an error? Please provide some real GPS data to show your issue.

Comment: I don't have an `ST_Contains(geography, geography)` here. What PostGIS version are you working with? I only have `ST_Contains(geometry, geometry)`. Also, are you sure you don't want `ST_ContainsProperly` or `ST_Within`?

Comment: If you're unsure about geography vs geometry see http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/6681/12379

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My approach would be to:

1. Assign a CRS (Coordinate Reference System) to the gps data (I assume they are in WGS84, thus srid 4326) via SRID (`ST_SetSRID(your_geom, 4326)` does this)
2. Then (Only possible if you assigned the srid 4326) cast them to geography (`::geography` does this) to enable setting the buffer radiae in meters,
3. And cast them back to geometry (`::geometry` does this) for the `st_contains` function to work

Query:

```
    SELECT ST_Contains(bigc::geometry,smallc::geometry) as bigcontainssmall 
from (select 
st_buffer(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-71.10434, 42.31506),4326)::geography,40) as smallc,
st_buffer(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-71.10434, 42.31507),4326)::geography,400) as bigc) foo
```